# How does 90/180 rule work while holding a Schengen residence?

Tags: schengen, norway, 90-180-visa-rules

I am an Indian citizen, holding a residence permit in Norway valid for 2 years. I want to know about the 90/180 rule.

Can I travel to Portugal for one week, come back to Norway and travel again for vacation for 2 weeks to Italy, and again come back to my residence country?

Does time spent in my residence country also count against my total stay in the Schengen area? Does Iit mean that the clock stops tickkng when person comes back to their residence country?

Comment: Since you have a Schengen residence permit, 90/180 rule doesn't apply to you.

Comment: But i have heard  somewhere that if u r holding a residence permit In any country In Schengen or europe u can jst travel for 90 days with In 180 days with In Schengen. But i am very confused about this rule.

Comment: For the correct answer, see [90/180 rule while holding a work permit from norway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/114646/19400).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*De jure* the rules of Schengen residents are the same as for non-EU nationals residing abroad: you can only spend 90 days in other Schengen countries out of the past 180 days.

However for all practical intents and purposes the 90/180 rule only exists on paper. In reality nobody knows about your movements within the Schengen area, so nobody can keep track of how many days you've spent in each country.

The only law that matters is the law within your country of residence, which might require that you maintain a certain activity (employment, study) during your stay. As long as you maintain that activity you can travel wherever you want for however long you want. This doesn't mean you can actually *live* abroad for an unlimited time, but regular tourist activities shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So it mean that the stay in the residence country matter. If am maintaining my activity like work etc. so there is no any problem to travel inside other schengen countries. Each time I return back to Norway from my short trip with in other schengen  member states only count my stay over there not inside the one that

Comment: @RajKaur correct, because nobody knows that you even left Norway in the first place.

Comment: It does not count the days in the Norway

Comment: Eg Am planning to travel Portugal on 21/08/18 and coming back to NORWAY on 26/08/18 And again traveling to Itly 22/11/18 and coming back on 27/11/18. Nd traveling again on 06/2/19 and coming back 16/02/19. Can i make all these trips as m holding a valid residence permit from Norway. In this situation how many days m going to consume? If my stay inside Norway will not gonna count so it means my total stay will be much less than 90 days. Is m right?

Comment: @RajKaur again, you **do not** consume any days in practice. Forget about the 90/180 rule if you're a Schengen resident.

Comment: So this rule does not work in practice if someone holding a valid residence permit in schengen.

Comment: @RajKaur yes, forget about it. Follow the rules in Norway and enjoy your travels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77327/discussion-between-raj-kaur-and-jonathanreez).

Comment: "you can travel wherever you want for however long you want": while this may be true in practice, it is not true *de jure,* so even in practice there could be cases where people get caught and punished.  The probability is, granted, exceedingly low, but the answer does not make that clear enough.

Comment: In my case. How can I obey this rule while traveling? I won't wanna exceed that limit of 90 days as I mention before. Should I assume that as long as I am just making short trips with in that limit and returning back to my residence country after every trip as it does not count stay in norway so it should be okey to make 2-3 trips with in a period of 180 days not spending more than 90 days. Is m rgt ?

Comment: @RajKaur yes, that is right.

Comment: That's what I wanna make sure. But while reading different interpretations I got very confuse.

Answer (score -3):

The rule 90/180 it is just to be sure that during the last 6 months you haven't spend more than 90 days in Europe.

You can go on a trip with no problem. And yes, the time spent in Norway counts against your total stay in the Schengen area. So even if you stay for 2 years without leaving Norway your Shengen VISA will, eventually, expire.

Note, however, that in the count of the 90 days those you have spent in Norway are not being taken into account.

Comment: so it mean that time spend In NORWAY Does not include In the calculation of my total stay In Schengen.

Comment: *It is* included in your total stay in Schengen.

Comment: IT mean if i travel to Portugal for one week and come back to NORWAY after one week. And travel to Itly for one week after spending 2 month In NORWAY. In this sense How Many days i am going to spend i Schengen ? Does IT means that i already consume my 90 day limit?

Comment: If your residence permit has a validity for 2 years then you can stay for 2 years in Norway entering or leaving for short periods of times to visit other countries (Portugal and Italy, e.g). If you had travel 1 week to Portugal, 2 weeks to Italy and have already been 2 months in Norway then you have already spent 2 months and 3 weeks of your VISA out of 24 months. 

90 day limit is not applying to you in this case as you have a redient permit for 2 years.

Comment: So IT means that 90 day rule Does not Apply to me since am holding a residence permit from NORWAY.  Can i  make some short trip with In Schengen In future during the validity of my residence permit

Comment: Yes, you can as long as your Shangai VISA is vigent.

Comment: Schengen visa is vigent means until i reach 90 days limit or there is no limit since k am holding a valid residence permit

Comment: I dont understand why whould my time spend inside NORWAY count in the time spend in another Schengen countries.

Comment: You have to check it in your VISA. I can't tell you the period of your VISA as it may vary depending on your circumstances, etc.

Comment: I have a work residence permit from NORWAY. IT allowed me to travel 90 days out of 180. I Want to Know if i could splitt 90 days over several visit inside Schengen while returning back to NORWAY after each short time stay Inside Schengen. Eg Am planning to travel Portugal on 21/08/18 and coming back to NORWAY on 26/08/18 And again traveling to Itly 22/11/18 and coming back on 27/11/18. Nd traveling again on 06/2/19 and coming back 16/02/19. Can i make all these trips AS m holding a valid residence permit from NORWAY

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  A residence permit issued by a Schengen country allows its bearer to stay in *other* Schengen countries subject to the 90/180 rule, and time in the issuing country does not count.  There is no counting of the "total stay in the Schengen area" including the issuing country, because there is no limitation of the duration of stay in the issuing country apart from the period of validity.  The reason for this rule is to prevent someone from using a residence permit from one country to live in another country.  The rule is not systematically enforced, but it still exists.

Comment: See for example [Travel Documents for non-EU Nationals](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm), which says "If you have a valid residence permit from one of those Schengen countries, it is *equivalent to a visa."* (emphasis added)