# 90/180 rule while holding a work permit from norway

Tags: norway

I am a Indian citizen holding a work residence permit from Norway for two years.  I want to make some trips in the rest of the Schengen area. I am planning my first trip to Portugal on 22/08/18 till 26/08/18, a second trip to Italy from 22/11/18 to 27/11/18, and again to Portugal from 06/02/19 to 16/02/19.  I will stay permanently  inside Norway after each trip to other Schengen countries.  How does the 90/180 rule work in this case?  Am I allowed to make all those trips while holding my residence permit in Norway? Can you let me know if I'm exceeding the 90-day limit with these trips?

Comment: I had a confusion with the answer of previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the 90/180 rule work in this case?

It works by not counting days that you spend in Norway while the permit is valid.  The wording in the English version of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) is ambiguous, but this is the most restrictive interpretation.  The actual text is in Article 6(2):

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

You also ask:

> Am I allowed to make all those trips while holding my residence permit in Norway?

Yes.  A Schengen residence permit or a they D visa (a "national" or "long-stay" visa) allows the bearer to spend up to ninety days of each 180-day period in the rest of of the Schengen area (apart from the country that issued the permit or visa).

> Can you let me know if I'm exceeding the 90-day limit with these trips?

The way it works is that time spent in Norway during the validity of the permit doesn't count, so you're not even going to come close to running afoul of the rule.

For the sake of argument, though, we can count.  Your first trip is five days long, the second is six days long, and the third is eleven days long, so that's a total of twenty-two days, which is of course far less than ninety.

Comment: So u mean that only time spend spend outside NORWAY during those trips counts. So In this sense am not breaking the rule of 90/180. Becoz if it counts the the time of my stay In NORWAY after each trip than i will be exceeding the 90 days limit within my first 2 trips if IT works so.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  I'll add a reference to the answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks for make me clear abt this. I was very much confuse.

Comment: @RajKaur thanks are not necessary, but are appreciated. Please do vote for the answer, and "accept" it by checking the check mark, if you found it helpful.  Accepting an answer isn't final; if someone posts a better answer later, you can accept it instead.

Comment: One more thing i want to clear  if its ok for me to splitt those 90 days over many short period travels within Schengen countries over a period of 180 days while returning back to my residence holder country (Norway ).

Comment: I had ask this question before than someone wrote to me that after time spend In norway after each trip to Schengen Also include In the calculation of 90 days. That's why i want to make it clear.

Comment: @RajKaur see [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/19400). The very point of the rule is to allow multiple visits. If everyone covered by the rule had to remain away for half a year after spending one or two days in the Schengen area, it would make no sense at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77309/discussion-between-raj-kaur-and-phoog).

Comment: It made me clear that there is no problem In splitting those 90 days over a period of 180 days. While staying within norway after each trip becoz the clock stop tickking. If m right? The thinks that confused me that i m going to splitt those days while staying In norway on my valid residence permit. Some people divide these days while hopping In and out of Schengen area, but In my case my residence permit help to stop that clock tickking every time i return back to norway from trip inside Schengen. Correct me if m wrong ?